# Curl fails in Linux, php 5.3.13

Tags: php, linux, curl

I've created a php code that sends 3 curl's and parse them. It works perfectly localy, but fails online.

I'm sure it's because of configuration difference, but I don't know how to explain this to the IT team.

This is what I have localy:

PHP Version 5.4.7

System  Windows NT USERPC 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Business Edition Service Pack 1) i586

And this is the server configs:
PHP Version 5.3.13

System  Linux (some srever ip stuff  here)

Does anyone know this to be the problem? Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong direction?

I'm not posting any code, because it's not coding issue- the code works great localy.

Thanks

Comment: Firewalls, routing, DNS, NAPT, Internet failure, quantum physics... can be many things...

Answer (score 0):

> ... I don't know how to explain this to the IT team.

Tell them the result of your calls to [`curl_errno()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) and [`curl_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php). That's the language that they understand.

Comment: As I said, there are no errors... A curl sent from localhost returns different results then a curl sent from the server. No errors here.

Comment: @user1223457: well then please expand your question with what results you are getting and which results you are expecting. The phrases "failing" and "different results" don't contain any information.

Comment: You did not say there are no errors. And if there really are no errors, what is the problem? Did you tell the IT team the values I have suggested? Did you even determine those values?